# How to remove dots from formated numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 3.2.14 app and in the view of this app I am using the jQuery plugin http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/ for formatting input fields.

This works very good but before I save to the database I want to remove all the dots.

This is the value coming in from the form:

12.345

I need it to be like this before saving:

12345

How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

I tried this:

```
def fixed_rate_cents=(value)
  super value.gsub(/\./mi, '')
end
```

But then I get:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError - unknown attribute: fixed_rate_cents:
```

Comment: Do you want to convert it on save and let it show on the screen with the point, or do you want to prevent the point from being used?

Comment: I want it to show in the view with dots but be saved into the database without dots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the model, just override the attribute setter, like so:

```
def my_attribute_to_monkey_with=(value)
   self[:my_attribute_to_monkey_with] =  value.to_s.gsub(/\./mi, '')
end
```

Comment: Yeah I have tried that. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Now I get NoMethodError - undefined method `gsub' for 12345678900:Fixnum:

Comment: Sorry but now I get: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::NumericValueOutOfRange: ERROR:  integer out of range

Comment: Your other solution worked. I was entering a too long sequense (1234567890).